# Making third List from two Lists for common names in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have two Java Lists. First list contains NAME column. Second List contains NAME and STATUS columns.

First List contains: David;  David

Second List contains: David, 3; David, 1; David, 2 ;John, 1; John 3;

For each common Name from two lists, i should make a third list in the following one Row.

Name Status1  Status2  Status3

David  1         2       3
John   1                 3

How can i achieve this using Java List Collection ?

My example: I created three classes which holds three lists. 
//First Class

public class FirstClass {
    private String name;

```
public FirstClass(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}
```

// setters and getters here
}

// Second Class

public class SecondClass {

```
private String name;

private int status; 

public SecondClass(String name, int status) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.status = status;
}
   // setters and getters here
```

}

// ThirdClass

public class ThirdClass {

```
private String name;    
private int status1;    
private int status2;    
private int status3;

public ThirdClass(String name, int status1, int status2, int status3) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.status1 = status1;
    this.status2 = status2;
    this.status3 = status3;
}

public ThirdClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

// setters and getters here
```

}

// Execution class

import java.util.*;

public class ClientExecute {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<FirstClass> a1 = new ArrayList<FirstClass>();

    a1.add(new FirstClass("David"));
    a1.add(new FirstClass("John"));
    a1.add(new FirstClass("David"));


    List<SecondClass> a2 = new ArrayList<SecondClass>();

    a2.add(new SecondClass ("John", 2));
    a2.add(new SecondClass ("David", 2));
    a2.add(new SecondClass ("David", 3));
    a2.add(new SecondClass ("David", 1));
    a2.add(new SecondClass ("John", 3));


ThirdClass third = null;

List<ThirdClass> a3 =null;

    for(FirstClass  first: a1) {

        third = new ThirdClass();
        a3 = new ArrayList<ThirdClass>();

        for( SecondClass second: a2) {

            if(first.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(second.getName())) {

                third.setName(second.getName());

                if(second.getStatus() ==1){

                    third.setStatus1(second.getStatus());
                }
                else if(second.getStatus() ==2){

                    third.setStatus2(second.getStatus());
                }
                else if(second.getStatus() ==3){

                    third.setStatus3(second.getStatus());
                }
            }

            a3.add(third);
        }

    }

    printThirdList(a3);

}

private static void printThirdList(List<ThirdClass> a3) {

            for(ThirdClass list: a3){
            System.out.println(list.getName()+list.getStatus1()+list.getStatus2()+list.getStatus3());   

            }
}
```

}

I think, i am doing wrong in iterating two lists while comparing. 
I am getting following wrong output:

```
    David 1 2 3;
    David 1 2 3;
    David 1 2 3;
    David 1 2 3;
    David 1 2 3;

   Expected Output:
    David 1 2 3;
    John  1   3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move the ArrayList of third class outside first loop.

Second, Remove a3.add from the second loop and put it in first loop since it is adding the same instance for every value of second class. This is causing multiple output.

```
List<ThirdClass> a3 = new ArrayList<ThirdClass>();

    for(FirstClass  first: a1) {

        ThirdClass third = new ThirdClass();

        for( SecondClass second: a2) {

            if(first.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(second.getName())) {

                third.setName(second.getName());

                if(second.getStatus() ==1){

                    third.setStatus1(second.getStatus());
                }
                else if(second.getStatus() ==2){

                    third.setStatus2(second.getStatus());
                }
                else if(second.getStatus() ==3){

                    third.setStatus3(second.getStatus());
                }
            }
        }
        a3.add(third);
    }
```